# PHP Generated CSV File filled with html crap from webhost instead of data?

Tags: php, csv, fputcsv

I am using PHP to generate a csv file with a first name and second name.

On my local XAMPP server it works fine and generate this output.

```
Andy,Murray
Sarah,Palin
Bob,Saget
```

However on this 000webhost.com free webhosting site I get the following output.

```
    <br><table border='1' cellpadding='2' bgcolor='#FFFFDF' bordercolor='#E8B900' align='center'><tr><td><font face='Arial' size='1' color='#000000'><b>PHP Error Message</b></font></td></tr></table><br />
<b>Warning</b>:  array_walk() [<a href='function.array-walk'>function.array-walk</a>]: The argument should be an array in <b>/home/a2806375/public_html/csv.php</b> on line <b>15</b><br />
<br><table border='1' cellpadding='2' bgcolor='#FFFFDF' bordercolor='#E8B900' align='center'><tr><td><div align='center'><a href='http://www.000webhost.com/'><font face='Arial' size='1' color='#000000'>Free Web Hosting</font></a></div></td></tr></table>
<!-- Hosting24 Analytics Code -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://stats.hosting24.com/count.php"></script>
<!-- End Of Analytics Code -->
```

This is my code:

```
function outputCSV($data) 
        {
            $outstream = fopen("php://output", "w");


            function __outputCSV(&$vals, $key, $filehandler) 
            {
                fputcsv($filehandler, $vals); // add parameters if you want
            }
            array_walk($data, "__outputCSV", $outstream);
            fclose($outstream);
        }



        $result = $db->fetch_array($result);

        header("Content-type: text/csv");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=guestlist.csv");
        header("Pragma: no-cache");
        header("Expires: 0");


        outputCSV($result);
```

Why is it doing this?

Is it because its a free hosting site and they are trying to put advertising in a CSV file?

How do I work around, I am a bit low on money atm so I cant afford a paid server.
Thanks

Comment: Well read the "html crap" and it'll tell you what's wrong.

Comment: Why is it working on my localhost then?

Comment: Probably because you have something in the database on your localhost.

Comment: I turned off error reporting but I am still getting the google analytics bit.

Comment: You don't actually show what line 15 is where the array_walk() is called - this may not be DB related, but code that comes earlier in your csv.php

Comment: Updated with my function that is giving the warning message

Comment: `var_dump($data)` in the function - whatever you're passing to it is not an array.

Comment: Array ( [0] => Bob [first_name] => Bob [1] => Saget [second_name] => Saget )

Comment: So, is that array_walk line in the code you posted line 15 from csv.php?  and is that var_dump from the server or your local version?  Finally, here's a thread on disabling the analytics:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268868/webhoster-inserts-a-javascript-which-brokes-my-code-how-to-remove-it

Comment: Thanks ernie, it turns out there was a difference in my db class file in localhost which used fetch_assoc instead of fetch_array. I really need to get some sort of versioning control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable the insertion of their analytics code from their control panel:

http://members.000webhost.com/analytics.php

From: http://www.000webhost.com/forum/faq/7894-faq-frequent-ask-questions-guide.html

Comment: Thanks coderabbi! Fixed the problem