# Receiving extra info from server response

Tags: php, android, sql-server, server-response

HI I am sending a username to my php file located on the server to check if the username exists in my database. If it does I want to send back a response which contains only "False", or else it will send back "True".

Here is my php code:

```
<?php

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['passsword'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

mysql_connect(//server name, server_admin, server_password) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("a1754417_word") or die (mysql_error());

$result = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM Users WHERE username = '$username'");

if(mysql_num_rows($result) != 0){
  echo mysql_num_rows;
  echo "False"; 
}else{
  echo "True";
}
?>
```

Here is my output from Logcat

```
01-13 03:16:34.606: I/Response 'False'(791): True
01-13 03:16:34.606: I/Response 'False'(791): <!-- Hosting24 Analytics Code -->
01-13 03:16:34.606: I/Response 'False'(791): <script type="text/javascript" src="http://stats.hosting24.com/count.php"></script>
01-13 03:16:34.606: I/Response 'False'(791): <!-- End Of Analytics Code -->
```

My code is sending back "True" correctly but it is also sending the extra information why?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, that your hoster has configured the server to append some analytics stuff. If you cannot disable it somewhere in a control panel, you might need to switch to a more reputable hoster. You could also try to modify the header with [header()](http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) to get rid of this:

Also, have a look at this question:

[Webhoster inserts a javascript which brokes my code how to remove it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2268868/1175253)