# want to Remove lines after the </body> WordPress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, templates, w3c-validation

I don't know how was those lines inserted after the end of my  tag in wordpress
i found 1 error in my site using W3C validator

```
</body>
</html>
<!-- Hosting24 Analytics Code -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://stats.hosting24.com/count.php"></script>
<!-- End Of Analytics Code -->
```

In the end of Footer.php file nothing after

how i do to remove the Hosting24 Analytics Code lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i'm not mistaken, this line of code is being added by your hosting company.
I guess that it's a free hosting company. I guess you can't remove it since it's being added after you're uploading the file or on the fly.

Anyway, Take a look at this solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2268958/998096

Just mentioning,

> by doing this you violate their policy and they will eventually drop
>   you from their service and you will lose all your data.

**So do it on your own risk.**