# Retrofit: MalformedJsonException despite right return

Tags: json, gson, retrofit

I always get an error from retrofit (gson):

```
retrofit.RetrofitError:com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException:
Use JsonReader.setLentient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 
column 15 path $
```

But in my opinion my return is right. It worked on my local server, but as I uploaded to webspace I always get this :/ In the case below I sent a JSONObject in form of {"string":"test"} and the webservice just returns it (and the answer actually reaches the device, but retrofit throws the error above). The relevant Logs from Retrofit:

```
   ---> HTTP POST http://mywebserver.net/set_string.php
   Content-Type: application/json
   Content-Length: 19
   {"string":"test"}
   ---> END HTTP (19-byte body)
   <--- HTTP 200 http://mywebserver.net/set_string.php (351ms)
   HTTP/1.1 200 OK
   Connection: close
   Content-Length: 188
   Content-Type: application/json
   Date: Tue, 26 May 2015 12:11:40 GMT
   Server: Apache
   X-Android-Received-Millis: 1432642297627
   X-Android-Response-Source: NETWORK 200
   X-Android-Sent-Millis: 1432642297438
   X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.17
   {"string":"test"}        
   <!-- Hosting24 Analytics Code -->
   <script type="text/javascript"
   src="http://stats.hosting24.com/count.php"></script>
   <!-- End Of Analytics Code -->
   <--- END HTTP (188-byte body)
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Where does the `"foo":"bar"` come from if "I sent a JSONObject in form of {"string":"test"} and the webservice just returns it" ? What about the `script` balise that seems added by your host `Hosting24`. The response doesn't seem to be a valid `JSON` anymore

Comment: This was just a testing string, I removed it but the error remains...

Comment: The webhoster is 000webhost, where can I see how the packets are manipulated?

Comment: Take a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268868/webhoster-inserts-a-javascript-which-brokes-my-code-how-to-remove-it