# Getting numbers from form via POST, not working, PHP

Tags: php, forms, post, get

I have 2 files. I'm trying to get the POST from one file to another, yet it's showing up as null for some reason. Please take a look:

> testx1.php

```
<?php

echo "<form method = 'post' action = 'testx2.php'>";

echo "<input type = 'number' name = 'number'>";
echo "<input type = 'submit'>";

echo "</form>";

?>
```

> testx2.php

```
<?php

$number = $_POST['number'];
echo $number;

?>
```

Expected output:

```
123
```

Actual output:

```
No output
```

Also, this shown up in the link for some reason:

```
/testx2.php?number=123
```

Comment: The reason that /testx2.php?number=123 is showing up as your address is because it thinks you are using the GET method instead of the POST method.

Comment: I'm using members.000webhost.com. It's a free web server.

Comment: `type="number"` has browser restrictions. I would suggest changing it to `type="text"` for the time being and testing that way.

Comment: @kojow7 But I specifically mention that I wanted to use the POST method in my form.

Comment: @the_pete It works as a text.

Comment: @frosty if it works as text and not number then it looks like you're hitting a browser restriction. I copied your code line for line and it works for me with `type="number"` so try it in another browser or just keep it as text during your testing phase and switch it to number later.

Comment: @frosty, yes, so there must be something else wrong with your code. Are you sure you copied and pasted all of your code exactly, because what you have here works fine. Maybe you forgot to close a quote or bracket, etc. in the original.

Comment: @the_pete type="number" will not change it from a POST to a GET request. There is something else going wrong here. In HTML standards if the type is not recognized it defaults to text anyhow.

Comment: @kojow I understand that, but aside from the misinterpretation of POST as GET, there could be another issue at hand and I'm addressing the problem from that side of things because the code works for me without issue.

Comment: @frosty what browser and version are you using?

Comment: According to this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268868/webhoster-inserts-a-javascript-which-brokes-my-code-how-to-remove-it your webhost adds extra stuff to your page. Maybe try typing an exit command at the bottom of both of your scripts to see if this solves the issue.

Comment: Why are you using two different SO accounts?

Comment: @kojow7 because I can't ask questions on this one even though I have just as many upvotes as downvotes.

Comment: It is because you were getting a lot of downvotes on this account. To be able to ask questions again fix your previous questions and/or start to get more upvotes by contributing good answers to other people's questions. Don't create a new account.

Comment: @kojow7 It's working again, for some reason. The number input. I didn't change anything.

Comment: @kojow7 This is insanity. It only works when I refreshed testx1.php to test it. If I don't refresh the page, nothing changes. That's why I wasn't getting the right outputs...

Comment: @frosty, yeah it helps to look at the page source code in the browser just to make sure it has the actual code you are expecting it to have.

Comment: @kojow7 Source code doesn't actually show the php code...does it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works just fine for me. Tested on Apache server.

Have you tried it with a different browser? It looks look your browser is interpreting the HTML markup incorrectly.

You mentioned you're using a free web host which I would avoid, especially for development. A decent hosting package is available for just a few dollars a month like Hostgator for example. Some web hosts, especially free ones, add so many weird configurations to their servers to limit users and "secure" their server that it renders some code useless.

When developing try installing Mamp or Xampp and use that to test your code locally.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe too late but you need to write "post" in Caps.

```
<?php

echo "<form method ="POST" action = 'testx2.php'>";

echo "<input type = 'number' name = 'number'>";
echo "<input type = 'submit'>";

echo "</form>";

?>
```