# Javascript unexpected code from server with JSON

Tags: javascript, php, json

```
<!-- Hosting24 Analytics Code -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://stats.hosting24.com/count.php"></script>
<!-- End Of Analytics Code -->
```

This is I'm getting at the end of the JSON, I don't from where it is coming. My JSON Parsing is getting failed because of these lines of code.

My API is in PHP.

Is it coming from the host? I've written a mail to them too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to manage your analytics code from here:
http://members.000webhost.com/analytics.php

use your user and password and disable it.

Regards,
Saar

Comment: Thanks Saar!! This ruined my whole day actually...Eventually solved though...Great work.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer has been addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268868/webhoster-inserts-a-javascript-which-brokes-my-code-how-to-remove-it). As mentioned below you can [configure your cPanel](http://members.000webhost.com/analytics.php) to stop tracking. A problem being your domain will be closed due to inactivity.

Alternatively you can add the following to the `.htaccess` file in your `public_html` which should stop tracking but maintain your hosting.

```
<FilesMatch "\.(php)$">
    php_value auto_append_file none
</FilesMatch>
```

[courtesy of wiseindy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18412190/2202642)

This shouldn't really be tolerated, I would advise you switch hosting services.

Comment: Thanks Deepak! This is just for testing, when I'm done I'll change the host for sure.

Comment: I'll migrate my API to AWS soon.