# Unable to see success message after form submit (AngularJS and PHP)

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, ajax

I have built a contact form with AngularJS and using PHP. Form is working perfectly and I able to receive emails. However, after the form is submitted I want to disable the submit button and display success message and vice - versa.

My code are as follows:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['jcs-autoValidate']);
app.run(['defaultErrorMessageResolver',
        function(defaultErrorMessageResolver) {
            defaultErrorMessageResolver.getErrorMessages().then(function (errorMessages) {
                errorMessages['validPhone'] = 'Please enter valid phone number';
            });
        }]);
app.controller('FormController', function($scope, $http){
   $scope.formData = {};
    $scope.result = 'hidden'
    $scope.submitButtonDisabled = false;
    $scope.submitted = false;
    $scope.submit = function(help) {
        $http({
            method : 'POST',
            url : 'process.php',
            data : $.param($scope.formData),
            headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        }) .success(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            if (data.success) {
                $scope.submitButtonDisabled = true;
                $scope.resultMessage = data.message;
                $scope.result = 'bg-sucess';
            } else {
                   $scope.submitButtonDisabled = false;
                   $scope.resultMessage = data.message;
                   $scope.result = 'bg-danger';
               }
        });
    }
});
```

PHP

```
<?php
require_once 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['phone']) && isset($_POST['message'])) {

    if (empty($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['phone']) || empty($_POST['message'])) {
        $data = array('success' => false, 'message' => 'Please the form completely.');
        echo json_encode($data);
        exit;
    }

    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    $mail->From = $_POST['email'];
    $mail->FromName = $_POST['name'];
    $mail->AddAddress('xxxx@gmail.com');
    $mail->Subject = $_POST['phone'];
    $mail->Body = "Name: " . $_POST['name'] . "\r\n\r\nMessage: " . stripslashes($_POST['message']);

    if (isset($_POST['ref'])) {
        $mail->Body .= "\r\n\r\nRef: " . $_POST['ref'];
    }
    if(!$mail->send()) {
        $data = array('success' => false, 'message' => 'Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo);
        echo json_encode($data);
        exit;
    }

    $data = array('success' => true, 'message' => 'Thank you for contacting us! We will get back to you soon.');
    echo json_encode($data);

} else {

    $data = array('success' => false, 'message' => 'Please the form completely.');
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

CONSOLE:

{"success":true,"message":"Thank you for contacting us! We will get back to you soon."}

You can also access the demo link for more information
http://newangularform.comlu.com/

Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: Share HTML template you are working with

Comment: Here is my HTML at JSfiddle alternately please check the link I have mentioned above for you can check it live, Thanks

https://jsfiddle.net/Achillies/d9z4moc5/

Comment: Your response is not proper. you can check in console. There is a script tag. But, there must be a JSON response or JSON string, So you can parse it in JSON

Comment: Could you please elaborate more as I have echo json_encode($data); in my PHP file... also even if the form is successful we get ng-binding as bg-danger!

Comment: Can you also update the Question with your `console.log(data)` ?

Comment: because you are checking if(data.status) which will never executes. It will leads to execute else case every time. that's why you are getting this. Just add debugger and debug it with yourself.

Comment: Updated with console...., Thank you Jitendra.. that is where I am stuck and could not find the way around...

Comment: I tried with if(data.error) now the button is disabled but still no message via  data binding if it was successful or error. I got the email though!... Inspect element showed bg-success but message was not displayed

Comment: {"success":true,"message":"Thank you for contacting us! We will get back to you soon."}
<!-- Hosting24 Analytics Code -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://stats.hosting24.com/count.php"></script>
<!-- End Of Analytics Code -->

Comment: the above should be {"success":true,"message":"Thank you for contacting us! We will get back to you soon."}

Comment: For testing purpose I am using free hosting service provider I deleted their default PHP file still I am getting that I guess will try on live server and will update you. Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268868/webhoster-inserts-a-javascript-which-brokes-my-code-how-to-remove-it

Comment: Dude you are awesome! it worked you can check too! thank you so much. Make it an answer I will accept it